# qemu/kvm image on dropbox

Tags: kvm-virtualization, dropbox, qemu

I am trying to upload my qemu/kvm image to Dropbox but for some reason the owner and group keeps changing to root and Dropbox can't upload. Following some tutorials on the web I have:

```
- updated the machine.xml with virsh edit $machine 
- changed the user and group to my user in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
```

but with no success.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it work if you copy it into a flash drive with a FAT partition and upload it from there?

Comment: It does work if I change manually the owner and the group to my user, but as soon as I start the virt manager the owner and the group is changed back to root and there I get: "can't sync file, permission denied"; now I am playing with a option found in qemu.conf -> 'dynamic_ownership=0' and seems to work; if I get it to work I will post an answer; thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04 adding the following to '/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf' solved my problem:

```
user = "myUser"
group = "myGroup"
dynamic_ownership = 0
```

For those who wish to move the qemu/kvm image to Dropbox, I did this as well:

```
virsh edit machineName
```

and then changed this line:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  ...
  <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/generic.qcow2' /> // removed
  <source file='/home/myUser/Dropbox/vm/generic.qcow2' /> // added
  ...
</disk>
```

You have to change owner and group of:

```
/home/myUser/Dropbox/vm/generic.qcow2
```

to yourUser and yourGroup. Hope this will help you.